# Draw a vertical line in a row in TableLayout android

Tags: android, graph, draw, tablelayout

When I use an empty view with some background, the view always stretches to full width, However I have mentioned android:layout_width="2dp"
Please help !

```
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow_uplines"
    android:layout_width="3dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical" 
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true">
    <View
        android:id="@+id/left_line"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_width="2dp"
        android:layout_height="160dp" 
        android:background="#DFDFDF"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical" 
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true">
    </View>
    <View
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_width="2dp"
        android:layout_height="160dp" 
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical" 
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true">
    </View>
    <View
        android:id="@+id/right_line"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_width="2dp"
        android:layout_height="160dp" 
        android:background="#DFDFDF"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical" 
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true">
    </View>
</TableRow>
```

Comment: please post your relevant xml so we can help you

Comment: This is one of the row

Answer (score 1):

### Solution:-

With layout_weight you can specify a size ratio between multiple views

You just need to remove the     `android:layout_weight="1"` line from the view that you want to make the line.It happens to you because linearlayout taking this view in consideration for stretching. 
So just remove this line..Enjoy.!